# C# this.Invoke broken, process classes event in GUI on different thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I tried to dive into multithreading once again and hit the ground quite fast (.Net 4.5).

I have a class library, which does some heavy byte-reading from files, raising an event.

```
public class cMyClass
{
public event EventHandler<cUpdateEventArgs> OnReadUpdate = delegate{ };
public int id {get; private set;}

public cMyClass(int in_id)
{ id = in_id; }

public async void ReadFromFile(string in_filePath)
{ // Do a bit of reading all bytes here and error-checking there...
//Here comes the heavy lifting
await ReadTriangles(stlBytes.SubArray(cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER, stlBytes.Length - cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER));
}

private Task ReadTriangles(byte[] in_triangles)
{
    UInt32 numberOfTriangles = BitConverter.ToUInt32(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_triangles.SubArray(0, 4)), 0);
    float percentage = 0;
    float percentageOld = percentage;
    OnReadUpdate(this, new cReadUpdateEventArgs(id, Resources.Texts.ReadingTriangles, percentage));
    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < numberOfTriangles; i++)
    {
        percentage = ((float)(i + 1)) / numberOfTriangles * 100;
        triangleList.Add(new cSTLTriangle(in_triangles.SubArray(Convert.ToInt32(i * cConstants.BYTES_PER_TRIANGLE + 4), Convert.ToInt32(cConstants.BYTES_PER_TRIANGLE))));
        if (percentage - percentageOld >= 0.1) //Just tell about .1-percentage increases
        {
            percentageOld = percentage;
            OnReadUpdate(this, new cReadUpdateEventArgs(id, Resources.Texts.ReadingTriangles, percentage));
        }
    }
    OnReadUpdate(this, new cReadUpdateEventArgs(id, Resources.Texts.ReadingTriangles, percentage));
    return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
}
}
```

As you can see, any instance of cMyClass would run the `ReadFromFile` Task on a different thread. So naturally - wanting to be thread-safe - I have to do some Invoking. But wait!

Moving on to a WindowsForms-Application is where things start to go wrong. I have a testing form with just two progressBars and a button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
        progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar2.Maximum = 1000;
        //Now the same code as from the console application:
        cSTLBinaryDataModel stlFile = new cSTLBinaryDataModel(1);
        cSTLBinaryDataModel stlFile2 = new cSTLBinaryDataModel(2);
        stlFile.OnReadUpdate += stlFile_OnReadUpdate;
        stlFile2.OnReadUpdate += stlFile_OnReadUpdate;
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        taskList.Add(new Task(new Action(() => stlFile.ReadFromFile(@"C:\temp\Test.stl"))));
        taskList.Add(new Task(new Action(() => stlFile2.ReadFromFile(@"C:\temp\Test.stl"))));
        foreach (Task t in taskList)
            t.Start();
        // I need Task.WaitAll to re-enable the button after all processing is done
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void stlFile_OnReadUpdate(object sender, cReadUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.id)
        {
            case 1:
                progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.percentage * 10)));
                break;
            case 2:
                progressBar2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                progressBar2.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.percentage * 10)));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works in so far, that the files are being processed in the background (I checked the Task manager) but the Task.WaitAll blocks my UI, so *after* everything is done, I can see the progressBars running up.

How can I wait for the Tasks to finish but at the same time keep the UI responsive?

Comment: You might need to know about [the difference between `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2819308/945456).

Comment: It somehow works now. Will update my post.

Comment: A console application doesn't have the concept of a UI thread; just a main thread that runs the application.

Comment: Maybe you should narrow down your post. It's a wall of text and code now.

Comment: Apparently, you think that await starts a new thread. Not so.

Comment: No, await hands the "focus" back to one layer above unitl what is awaited is finished. It is what I am awaiting that is under a new thread, isnt't is?

Comment: How is that different from starting a thread? You think that ReadTriangles runs in a new thread. That is not the case because await does not start threads. This can't be just by contradiction: The moment you hand a task to await that task is already running. await is too late to influence where it runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to dive into multithreading once again...

Multithreading is totally old-school. These days, for I/O-bound opeations, use [`async`/`await` and the patterns that go along with it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) (i.e., `IProgress<T>` for progress updates). You'll find your life a lot easier.

These principles will help:

- Write synchronous code if the code is synchronous, and only use `async`/`await` if the code is asynchronous. In the code you posted, `ReadTriangles` should not have an asynchronous signature.
- Get rid of the event. Cross-thread events are messy. Instead, use `IProgress<T>`.
- Avoid `async void`; use `async Task` instead.

Here's how your class would look with these principles in place:

```
public async Task ReadFromFileAsync(string in_filePath, IProgress<cUpdateEventArgs> progress)
{
  // Do a bit of reading all bytes here and error-checking there...
  //Here comes the heavy lifting
  ReadTriangles(stlBytes.SubArray(cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER, stlBytes.Length - cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER), progress);
}

private void ReadTriangles(byte[] in_triangles, IProgress<cUpdateEventArgs> progress)
{
  UInt32 numberOfTriangles = BitConverter.ToUInt32(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_triangles.SubArray(0, 4)), 0);
  float percentage = 0;
  float percentageOld = percentage;
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report(new cReadUpdateEventArgs(id, Resources.Texts.ReadingTriangles, percentage));
  for (UInt32 i = 0; i < numberOfTriangles; i++)
  {
    percentage = ((float)(i + 1)) / numberOfTriangles * 100;
    triangleList.Add(new cSTLTriangle(in_triangles.SubArray(Convert.ToInt32(i * cConstants.BYTES_PER_TRIANGLE + 4), Convert.ToInt32(cConstants.BYTES_PER_TRIANGLE))));
    if (percentage - percentageOld >= 0.1) //Just tell about .1-percentage increases
    {
      percentageOld = percentage;
      if (progress != null)
        progress.Report(new cReadUpdateEventArgs(id, Resources.Texts.ReadingTriangles, percentage));
    }
  }
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report(new cReadUpdateEventArgs(id, Resources.Texts.ReadingTriangles, percentage));
}
```

And here's one way you could use it. Note the use of `Task.Run` *in the UI layer* to push the CPU-bound work off the UI thread:

```
cSTLBinaryDataModel stlFile = new cSTLBinaryDataModel(1);
cSTLBinaryDataModel stlFile2 = new cSTLBinaryDataModel(2);
var progress = new Progress<cReadUpdateEventArgs>(update =>
{
  switch (update.id)
  {
    case 1:
      progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(update.percentage * 10);
      break;
    case 2:
      progressBar2.Value = Convert.ToInt32(update.percentage * 10);
      break;
  }
});
await Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(() => stlFile.ReadFromFileAsync(@"C:\temp\Test.stl", progress)),
    Task.Run(() => stlFile2.ReadFromFileAsync(@"C:\temp\Test.stl", progress)));
button1.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it and try to adapt it to my code. I figured the Task.WhenAll() out by myself just now ;-)

Comment: Why did you make ReadFromFileAsync async?

Comment: @usr: I'm assuming that the code `// Do a bit of reading all bytes here` will use `await`.

Comment: No, actually it won't. Its just a File.ReadAllBytes and some size-checking. ReadTriangles is the heavy lifting.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk: I'd recommend using `await`, since that's I/O. But if you just want to get it working for now, you could change `ReadFromFileAsync` to return `void` instead of `Task` (and remove the `async` keyword). And drop the `Async` suffix (rename it to `ReadFromFile`). It won't be the most efficient, but it will work.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Works like a charm! This pushes the responsibility to do multithreading to whichever application implements my library? Is this best practice or just useful in my scenario? Progress/IProgress is nice!

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk: If your library methods are CPU-bound, then they should expose synchronous signatures. Yes, that means that it's the consumer's responsibility to push it to a background thread if necessary. UI apps will generally do this; ASP.NET apps will not. Console apps may or may not.

Comment: @StephenCleary: And another day where I have learned something :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course the UI doesn't update if you call `Task.WaitAll`. This stops the UI thread until all tasks are finished.

One way to go could be: For every task you start, increment a `private volatile int runningTasks` variable. Whenever a task finishes, call another event. In the handler for that event

1. Decrement the variable again
2. When it reaches 0, activate the button again

You need to decide whether you want to be fully asynchronous or fully synchronous.

Example:

private volatile int runningTasks = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        runningTasks = 2;

```
    ...

    stlFile.OnReadUpdate += stlFile_OnReadUpdate;
    stlFile2.OnFinished += stlFile_OnFinished;
    stlFile.OnReadUpdate += stlFile_OnReadUpdate;
    stlFile2.OnFinished += stlFile_OnFinished;

    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    taskList.Add(...);
    taskList.Add(...);
    foreach (Task t in taskList)
        t.Start();
}

private void stlFile_OnFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    runningTasks--;
    if (runningTasks <= 0)
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => button1.Enabled = true));
}
```

Comment: Well, the whole point of using asyncronous methods an threads is (e.g.) to keep the UI responsive, isn't it? But, listening for a "I am finished"-event could be an Idea.

Comment: Yes, but you have to do it right. If you block the UI thread it doesn't matter how many threads you spawn, the UI will not be responsive.